# Scala construct objects with or without arguments

Tags: scala, constructor

In Scala, need a class that will construct a default object based on predefined computation (below the code may not be syntactically correct, but the idea is shown) if its no-params constructor is called. And I will be able to test its methods by creating an object with `this(i, s)` and parameters created outside. What is the best way to do that?

```
class myobj(i: Int, s: String) {
    def this() = {
        val j = 7 // in reality more computation with extra vals involved
        val i = j
        val str = "abcdefg"
        val s = str.get(indexOf (i % 5))
        this(i, s)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be better with a static factory:

```
class MyObj(i: Int, s: String)

object MyObj {
  def apply() = {
    val j = 7 // in reality more computation with extra vals involved
    val i = j
    val str = "abcdefg"
    val s = ""
    new MyObj(i, s)
  }
}
```

Then you can just do:

```
val o = MyObj()
```

Comment: Thank you, did like you suggested. Do you know how can I then retrieve `o.i` and `o.s`. The compiler tells me `value i is not a member of object`

Comment: @StephanRozinsky add `val` to class definition: `class MyObj(val i: Int, val s: String)`

Comment: make MyObj a case class instead of a class and you should be able to access the parameters...

Comment: @Sergey Lagutin дзякуй :)